# Layout cell subviews at initialization using custom dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Question - short version**

Despite configuring my cell height to be 112, my cells get instantiated at the standard height of 44. This messes up my subviews unless I use extra resources and call `cell.layoutSubviews`

**Context:**

I made a subclass of `UITableViewCell` called `ResearchCell`, where in the `init`, I do the following:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    print(NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame)) // prints out the standard 320*44 cell
    manageViews()
}
```

I am using a `xib` for my cell:

[image]

**My Setup so far**

In the `ViewController`, I call the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
researchTableView.dataSource = researchDataSource
researchTableView.delegate = self
researchTableView.register(ResearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ResearchCell")
```

I also call the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 112.0
}
```

In `researchDataSource`, I do the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ResearchCell", for: indexPath) as! ResearchCell
    cell.topLineLabel?.text = "Hola"

    cell.layoutSubviews() //At the moment I have to call this to re-layout the views
    return cell
}
```

**Problem**

Unless I call `cell.layoutSubviews()` (see comment above), the cell automatically assumes the standard size of 320*44, and all the views I have programmatically laid out in the cell are all jumbled up. The cell should be a height of **112**, which I have specified in both my `xib` and the `tableView.delegate`. However, why is it not carried forth to cell creation?

Any pointer is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the class and not your custom nib. Change the following:

```
researchTableView.register(ResearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ResearchCell")
```

To:

```
researchTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ResearchCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ResearchCell")
```

This will then load the nib from your bundle instead of instantiating the class.

Comment: Thank you - this was indeed the issue.